# Trying to read html page from a web site using AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: ios7, xcode5, afnetworking-2

I'm trying to have my app load an HTML web page into a "responseObject" that I can later parse.

Here is my code:

```
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/xhtml+xml"];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"ghinno": @"1151213"};
    [manager GET:@"http://m.ghin.com/HLR.aspx" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         NSLog(@"HTTP: %@", responseObject);
         } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
              NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

...and this is the output.  I should be seeing the html from the webpage.  Can you help me understand what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, the answer lies below...

Essentially, it was an encoding / decoding of the response object that was causing my issues.  Here is the final solution:  (notice the line beginning with "NSString)...

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://m.ghin.com/HLR.aspx?ghinno=1151213"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", string);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
[op start];
```